# How do I prevent xargs from running multiple commands?

Tags: bash, xargs

I operate on lists of arguments of unknown total lengths in the format of `find /home -type f -size +512k -print0` output. The order of the arguments is significant.

I need to pass them in a command line such as what gets invoked by piping that to `xargs -r0 -- "${DANGEROUS_COMMAND[@]}" --log-file="${LOG_FILE_PATH}" --dry-run --`
But I need to guarantee that `"${DANGEROUS_COMMAND[@]}"` is executed **exactly once**, with **every single argument** or if the list was too long or empty we need to gracefully abort before running anything.

It needs to be safe to run a command first with a dry-run argument (subsequent invocations would destroy the previous invocation's log file), then run tests on the log file, and only if those all passed too to finally run the command again without the dry-run argument. I need to be able to trust that the log file reflects the whole list!

For weeks, I have erroneously thought that the

```text
-x, --exit
       Exit if the size (see the -s option) is exceeded.
```

switch in the `XARGS(1)` man page does this, but it only seems to do anything if a **single** input argument is too long, otherwise `xargs` still splits the arguments in multiple invocations of the command and I have almost certainly erroneously deleted something because of this. :(

It seems `xargs` does not provide a way to do this.
Is there a similar tool that does what I described or is writing something custom the only way to do this?

Comment: @KamilCuk That would mean to invoke the command one-by-one for every argumet. I want the opposite of that.

Comment: @KamilCuk A list of one argument can be too long if the argument by itself plus the command base is longer than the maximum possible command line. (I don't know the specifics of this, but I'm almost certain it wouldn't be possible to run a command line that would take a gigabyte by itself, for example, and thus if a single argument would itself be a gigabyte in length, it would make any command line too long)

Comment: You did not specify, which `xargs` you are using (Gnu, BSD), but for Gnu xargs, you can catch the case that the list is empty with the option `--no-run-if-empty`.  You can't tell xargs to abort if it needs more than one child process. If this is a requirement, I would not use `xargs` at all, but create an array of files and simply parameter-substitute the array. If these are too many elements, the bash will report an _argument list too long_ and refuse to execute the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest there is should be working fine.

```
readarray -t -d '' arr < <(find /home -type f -size +512k -print0)
if ((${#arr[@]})); then
    if "${DANGEROUS_COMMAND[@]}" --log-file="${LOG_FILE_PATH}" --dry-run -- "${arr[@]}"; then
        "${DANGEROUS_COMMAND[@]}" --log-file="${LOG_FILE_PATH}" -- "${arr[@]}"
    fi
fi
```